# Access Installation Disc from Azure-hosted Windows Server 2012 R2 VM

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

I'm setting up an ADFS farm in Windows Azure and I need to export the settings of my old farm to import to the new farm.  The official documentation on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486787.aspx) tells me to use scripts that are located in the **media/server_en-us/support/adfs folder** of the Windows Server 2012 R2 installation disc.  Considering this VM instance was one of the stock images in Azure, I don't have access to the contents of the Windows Server 2012 R2 installation disc.  I have no access to one on-premise either.  I'd rather not search for, download, and use an unofficial instance of these PowerShell scripts since they are likely non-trivial and it would be a serious security concern to setup a new ADFS environment with them.

What are my options and why would Microsoft not have made these generally available as a download?

UPDATE: Please vote for this suggestion if you feel Microsoft should provide us with the installation media in Windows Azure.  http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/5714393-make-installation-media-available-mount-an-iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just download a trial version of the ISO. and grab the scripts from there.

Comment: It does answer the question on how he can get his hands on the scripts... As to *why* MS did it the way they did, only MS can answer that :)

Comment: It's not a bad solution.  It's probably my only safe solution.  Thanks Trondh.