# Unable to install SMB v1.0/CIFS on Azure Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to install the "SMB 1.0/CIFS client" feature on an Azure based Windows Server 2019 VM but it can't find the source. Normally, on a physical server or a private VM, I'd mount the original ISO and browse to the "Sources\SxS" folder. However one never gets to "see" the install medium on an Azure provisioned server - I'm guessing it's cloned from a template.

I've got a copy of the Windows Server 2019 evaluation ISO - can I use that?

[image]

There is a similar question here but the answer is "try" so not certain and also the question was about W2012: [Access Installation Disc from Azure-hosted Windows Server 2012 R2 VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/584959/access-installation-disc-from-azure-hosted-windows-server-2012-r2-vm)

UPDATE: this doesn't appear to be a problem with source as mounting a Windows Server 2019 ISO doesn't help - there are not related files in the SXS folder.

Comment: It seems like this would be simple enough to test. Mount the ISO and try it.

Comment: Always get twitchy on production servers but I have just tried it and sources still not found. So suspect source missing message might be a bit of a red herring...

Comment: It sounds like it is a red herring. I don't recall seeing the prompt for alternate source when installing SMBv1 on Windows Server 2019. Are you able to install any role or feature?

Comment: Yes I was able to install the DFS namespace role. Just looked in the sxs folder on the ISO and there is nothing to suggest it's got the SMB feature: https://i.imgur.com/cNqMfzD.png

Comment: I've got a test W2019 VM lurking around on VMware Workstation - will give it a go there

Comment: Looks like SMB 1 is not allowed in new Azure VMs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/smb-version-1-disabled-azure-gallery-windows-operating-system-images/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actively prevents the SMB v1 feature being enabled on Windows Server 2019 when running on the Azure platform for well documented security reasons.

I was trying to enable SMB v1 to diagnose why a QNAP NAS was unable to mount a share from Windows Server 2019 but could from Windows Server 2016. The reason is because this particular NAS is still using SMB v1 to mount remote shares and can't be reconfigured otherwise. Therefore this operation is impossible with W2019 in Azure.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted for it to stop floating around and for future visitors to see this question has a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

SMB 1.0 is disabled in Azure VM’s since August 2017 when Microsoft established that this is a bug, a third-party application issue or a by-design behavior.

So you won't be able to install it in Azure VM. I was struggling with same issue until I found this article.

https://toptechnotes.com/smb-1-0-disabled/